# Trying to use URL to complete a form with JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, parameters

We have just got a new CRM system that manages our online forms and I can manipulate it using JQuery to complete extra functions.

This is something we are doing on our current website where I am able to use pathnames to complete sections of the form.

For example... `<URL>/John%20Smith/50` would preload the form with `John Smith` under `name` and `£50` under `donation`.

Here is my current code for the new system:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener( 'load', function() {
    var pageName = $(location).attr('pathname').split('/');
    var arr = $.makeArray(pageName);    
    $('input[name=field[91]]').eq(0).val(arr);
    $('input[name=field[9]]').eq(1).val(arr);
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're sharing some discovery or you have some actual problem to solve? Also... why is `<script>` inside `<style>` ?

Comment: See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9s3eugc8/

Answer (score 1):

I am posting it as an answer here:

```js
// suppose window.location = "https://<your url>/John%20Smith/50"
var url = "https://<your url>/John%20Smith/50";

$(document).ready(function(){

    // $(location).attr('pathname').split('/')
    // replace this with the above code
    var pageName = url.split('/').splice(3);
    var arr = $.makeArray(pageName);    

    // if name is unique, you don't need .eq
    // you may not need decodeURIComponent if url is form window.location
    $('input[name="field[91]"]').val(decodeURIComponent(arr[0]));
    $('input[name="field[9]"]').val('£' + decodeURIComponent(arr[1]));

});
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9s3eugc8/